# WPF Setter Class

Tags: c#, wpf, expression

I want to create a button in c# with no content but just a image within it.

I dont know how to use the setter. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
            Setter setter = new Setter();
            setter.Property = Image.SourceProperty;
            setter.Value = "asd.jpg";  //<--error

            Style Rstyle = new Style();
            Rstyle.TargetType = typeof(Button);
            Rstyle.Setters.Add(setter);

            Button _Button = new Button()
            {
                Width = 41,
                Height = 41
            };

            _Button.Style = Rstyle;
```

What should i put at setter.Value to obtain the image which resides in the project directory. "asd.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matter of this question Setters are not necessary. Setters are used in Triggers and Styles, whether in C# or in XAML.

Just use this code.

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage()
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/Resources/myImage.png");
bmp.EndInit();
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bmp;
myButton.Content = image;
```

Answer (score 4):

`Button` has a `Content` property that you can just dump a `BitmapImage` in it:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your source"));
TheButton.Content = image;
```

Comment: @RStyle You don't have to. BitmapImage can handle a JPEG by itself just fine.

Comment: Hey why does the image only show up if i do it by the method listed below answered by "dowhilefor". After creating the bitmapimage we need to use the Image class and then assign it to content.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="image"> //XAML in window resources tag
            <Image Source="Save.png"/>
   </ControlTemplate>


btn.Template =  (ControlTemplate)FindResource("image");
```

I think this is more flexible and reusable.